# Creating zip file in memory and returning as part of class to javascript client

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, zip

I have seen several articles explaining how to create a zip file in memory, and also how to download a file with javascript. Nothing exactly covers what I'm trying to do.

In my ASP Net Core application, a form posts to the controller and does several processing steps, culminating in creating one to many different physical files on the server (works fine), then creating a specifically named zip file containing these files (works fine).  I then want to return an object containing several bits of information: number of things processed, overall status of completion, path to the archive to download.

I can pass my object back and retrieve all this information just fine.

```
Object that is returned:

public class UpdateResultsVM 
{
    public int ClaimUpdateReturn {get; set; }
    public string ClaimUpdateMsg {get; set; }
    public string ZipFile {get; set; } // full physical path to archive
    public bool Completed {get; set; }
    public string Message {get; set; }
}


                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/Work/PerformProcess",
                            data: { IDs: IDs, LetterID: LetterID },
                            dataType: "json",

                            success: function (result) {
                                d.resolve(result);

                                if (result.ClaimUpdateReturn === 0) {
                                    console.log("returned 0");
                                    // error handling
                                }
                                else if (result.ClaimUpdateReturn === 1) {
                                    //console.log("returned 1");
                                    
                                    if (result.Completed === true && result.ZipFile !== null) {
                                        //console.log("got something to download: " + result.ZipFile);
                                        var zipfilepath = result.ZipFile;
                                        var zipfilename = zipfilepath.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop();
                                        console.log("path " + zipfilepath + " name " + zipfilename);
                                        var a = document.createElement('a');
                                        document.body.appendChild(a);
                                        a.style= "display: none";
                                        a.href = zipfilepath;
                                        a.download = zipfilename;
                                        a.click();
                                        document.body.removeChild(a);
 
                                        console.log("done with download");
                                        
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    //console.log("else statement");
                                    // do some other stuff
                                    
                                }

                            },
                            error: function (response) {
                                alert("There was an error in updating " " + response.Message);
                                d.resolve(response);

                            }
                        });
```

The controller function to create the zip file is such:

```
// modify to return in-memory binary data of zip instead?
        public string CreateZipFile(string destinationDirectory, string tagName, List<string> Documents)
        {
            string FileName;
            try
            {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(destinationDirectory, "TempOutput");
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);

                string zipName = filePath + "\\" + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tagName) ? "Zip_" : tagName + "_") + DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff") + ".zip";

                using (ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.Open(zipName, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
                    foreach (string document in Documents)
                    {
                        zip.CreateEntryFromFile(document, Path.GetFileName(document));
                        // these need to remain as physical files, they
                        // are used elsewhere in the app. 
                    }

                FileName = zipName;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // stuff
            }
            return FileName;
        }
```

But the physical location of the created zip file is not under web root, so it throws an error when I attempt to download it in this manner. I can't place it under web root.

Having a physical file created on the server is actually not optimal, since I will then have to do some cleanup to remove these files, all uniquely named.  So I'm thinking to convert to doing this archive file in memory instead.

I am relatively clear how I can modify the controller to create a zip file in memory, although input is definitely welcome. I'm thinking that I might want to add to UpdateResultsVM the actual binary contents of the zip file and download that, retaining the passed string ZipFile to name it for download. Tried several things and I can't get this to work. I need to be able to return all this information AND the generated file name for the download.

What type should I use to capture the in-memory zip file, and what do I need to do in my javascript to successfully download this zip file?

Comment: you can return a File to the browser and it will download it.  If you wanted to output memory do something like this:    var memory = new MemoryStream(); using (var stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(sWebRootFolder, sFileName), FileMode.Open))
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
            }
            memory.Position = 0;

            return File(memory, "application/zip", sFileName);

Comment: That's not the question.  I need to return an object which CONTAINS the memory stream representing the zip file, because I need those other pieces of information returned as well from the ajax call.

Comment: Don't handle that through javascript... the File can be sent directly from the controller to the browser.... (so get your data, and then send a post from the browser... you can actually do both at that same time by sending a standard GET or POST to a hidden iframe and also calling your JS.... if you need the JS results first, you can just update the iframe's SRC, or trigger a submit there... during the callback.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem.  I added a new member to the UpdateResultsVM byte[] ZipFileData. In my controller, I'm filling in both the unique file name for download, and generating the zip file in memory and putting that byte[] data into ZipFileData.

In my javascript, I'm now doing the following and it's working great:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
var binaryData = [];
binaryData.push(result.ZipFileData);
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(b64toBlob(binaryData, 'application/zip'), { type: "application/zip" });
a.href = url;
var link = result.ZipFile; // the name of the file to download
a.download = link;
document.body.append(a);
a.click();
a.remove();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

I found the b64toBlob function on some related answer here on StackOverflow, now I can't find it, but the function is:

```
var b64toBlob = function (b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
contentType = contentType || '';
sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
var byteArrays = [];

for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
    var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

    var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
}

var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
return blob;
```

};

Comment: just a note that there's a 2gb limit to objectURLs.  (It could also be limited by memory depending on device/browser)